# Facebook Flex SDK will not import, any ideas?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to setup the Facebook sdk for Flex for the first time. I simply copied the Graph API 1.6 web into my lib folder. And when i try and import it, it even shows up as you type, as you can see in img1. But after i save my project I get an error saying it cannot be found. Does anyone know how i should properly setup the facebook flex sdk?

edit: figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that line read either

```
import com.facebook.graph.*;
```

or

```
import com.facebook.graph.SomeClass;
```

?

I always rely on Flex Builder to organize my `import` statements. That way I never really have to deal with these errors.

Comment: Agreed, probably just a bad import statement.  Just remove it altogether and go where the errors are and do ctrl+space to import it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i feel pretty dumb lol. I'm just used to not doing more than 3 dots, i didnt even consider anything beyond the graph. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a flashbuilder's bug.

Two steps:

1. project => clean => build
2. restart your flashbuilder